# Does the integral of $\int_0^2 (\ln x)^{-2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Does the integral of $$\int\limits_0^2 \frac1{(\ln x)^2}$$ exist?

I tried using a series expansion for $x\to 1$ by saying this behaviour is like $\ln(1+x)$ as $x\to 0$. So I then used the series expansion for $\ln(1+x)$ but then got stuck there as I struggled to manipulate it as it's a denominator.

How would I go about seeing if it exists? The answer is yes according to my lecturer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not at $x=0$, at which the integrand approaches zero.  The problem is at $x=1$, at which the integrand behaves as $1/(x-1)^2$.  So, as constituted, the integral does not exist.

Comment: ..even in a principal value sense.(+1)

Comment: I meant that as x tends to 1 for lnx, it's as if x is tending to 0 for ln(1+x). But surely 0 is still a problem as we don't know whether the integral is finite as x tends to 0 or not?
Also, how does it behave like 1/(x−1)^2?

Comment: @hhattiecc: 1) it is finite - integrate by parts.  2) $\log{(1+x)} \sim x \implies \log{x} \sim x-1$.